# Does Hyperledger Fabric evaluate transaction return a signed query result?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-chaincode

When a transaction is submitted to a chaincode, read-write sets are returned along with the signature of the endorsing peer, and then the transaction proposal along with the endorsing singatures are sent to the ordering service. I want to know what happens when a query request is made to the chaincode.

Say I want to query the world state of an asset. I call the evaluateTransaction method. Is the output of this method signed by the endorsing peers as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first paragraph of your question

reference https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/orderer/ordering_service.html#orderers-and-the-transaction-flow ，we saimple divide tx flow into two step,proposal and ordering,when you query chaincode, just need proposl without involving ordering,after proposal success, you will get result.

For the second paragraph of your question

In the fabric v1.4.2 sources code,which at `peer/chaincode/common.go`,the function `chaincodeInvokeOrQuery` is used as chaicode query or invoke and this method will call method `ChaincodeInvokeOrQuery`

in the comment of method `ChaincodeInvokeOrQuery`

```
// ChaincodeInvokeOrQuery invokes or queries the chaincode. If successful, the
// INVOKE form prints the ProposalResponse to STDOUT, and the QUERY form prints
// the query result on STDOUT.
```

this means if you call chaincode query in cli or terminal,It will output the result(asset value) On STDOUT,and the chaincode invoke will output ProposalResponse

but you can observe that ChaincodeInvokeOrQuery return same format result(ProposalResponse) what ever you call query or invoke,**this means the result of query include the endorsing signature as well**,but we choose not to output it.

```
func ChaincodeInvokeOrQuery(
    spec *pb.ChaincodeSpec,
    cID string,
    txID string,
    invoke bool,
    signer msp.SigningIdentity,
    certificate tls.Certificate,
    endorserClients []pb.EndorserClient,
    deliverClients []api.PeerDeliverClient,
    bc common.BroadcastClient,
) (*pb.ProposalResponse, error) {
    // Build the ChaincodeInvocationSpec message
    invocation := &pb.ChaincodeInvocationSpec{ChaincodeSpec: spec}

    creator, err := signer.Serialize()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.WithMessage(err, fmt.Sprintf("error serializing identity for %s", signer.GetIdentifier()))
    }

    funcName := "invoke"
    if !invoke {
        funcName = "query"
    }

    // extract the transient field if it exists
    var tMap map[string][]byte
    if transient != "" {
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(transient), &tMap); err != nil {
            return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "error parsing transient string")
        }
    }

    prop, txid, err := putils.CreateChaincodeProposalWithTxIDAndTransient(pcommon.HeaderType_ENDORSER_TRANSACTION, cID, invocation, creator, txID, tMap)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.WithMessage(err, fmt.Sprintf("error creating proposal for %s", funcName))
    }

    signedProp, err := putils.GetSignedProposal(prop, signer)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.WithMessage(err, fmt.Sprintf("error creating signed proposal for %s", funcName))
    }
    var responses []*pb.ProposalResponse
    for _, endorser := range endorserClients {
        proposalResp, err := endorser.ProcessProposal(context.Background(), signedProp)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, errors.WithMessage(err, fmt.Sprintf("error endorsing %s", funcName))
        }
        responses = append(responses, proposalResp)
    }

    if len(responses) == 0 {
        // this should only happen if some new code has introduced a bug
        return nil, errors.New("no proposal responses received - this might indicate a bug")
    }
    // all responses will be checked when the signed transaction is created.
    // for now, just set this so we check the first response's status
    proposalResp := responses[0]
   
    //till here,query and invoke almost same,if invoke ,it will continue execution 
      ordering step,if query ,it will return 

    if invoke {
        if proposalResp != nil {
            if proposalResp.Response.Status >= shim.ERRORTHRESHOLD {
                return proposalResp, nil
            }
            // assemble a signed transaction (it's an Envelope message)
            env, err := putils.CreateSignedTx(prop, signer, responses...)
            if err != nil {
                return proposalResp, errors.WithMessage(err, "could not assemble transaction")
            }
            var dg *deliverGroup
            var ctx context.Context
            if waitForEvent {
                var cancelFunc context.CancelFunc
                ctx, cancelFunc = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), waitForEventTimeout)
                defer cancelFunc()

                dg = newDeliverGroup(deliverClients, peerAddresses, certificate, channelID, txid)
                // connect to deliver service on all peers
                err := dg.Connect(ctx)
                if err != nil {
                    return nil, err
                }
            }

            // send the envelope for ordering
            if err = bc.Send(env); err != nil {
                return proposalResp, errors.WithMessage(err, fmt.Sprintf("error sending transaction for %s", funcName))
            }

            if dg != nil && ctx != nil {
                // wait for event that contains the txid from all peers
                err = dg.Wait(ctx)
                if err != nil {
                    return nil, err
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return proposalResp, nil
}
```